# merging arrays with jquery grep

Tags: jquery

I have two array ArrayA and ArrayB. Array B may have some values in it that belong to ArrayA. I'm looking to have ArrayB contain all the values of ArrayA. So far, this is what I have:

```
for (i=0 ; i < ArrayB.length; i++)
{
  ArrayB = jQuery.grep(ArrayB, function (a) {
  ....
  };
};
```

I'm having some trouble with this function. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayB = jQuery.grep(ArrayB, function (a,i){
                   return jQuery.inArray(a, ArrayA) != -1;
         });
```

Comment: it's not working, may be the i index should be included somewhere.

Comment: Fixed (`inArray` returns a position, not a boolean). You want to remove all elements from ArrayB that are not in ArrayA, right?